# NextJS URLs and dynamic routing to index route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, next.js, vercel

I'm trying to route my blog posts from `/blog/[slug]` to `/[slug]`. Is there a way to do that? I've looked at the NextJS docs, but the examples show only nested url paths.

For example, on my `/blog` page, a list of Posts is shown. I want to be able to click on a post and go to `localhost:3000/my-blog-post` instead of `localhost:3000/blog/my-blog-post`. How would I go about doing that? I'm using the `Link` component if that makes a difference.

Edit with updated info:
I've tried the `as` prop on `Link` and Next requires it to be in the nested path format otherwise it throws an error.

Comment: Maybe the `as` prop? https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link

Comment: Thanks for responding. I tried that and `as` also requires the path to be nested.

Comment: why don't you move your `[slug].js` file to the `pages` folder instead of `blog` folder?